# Some Applications stay in Dock after closing

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, finder, dock

[image: Not killable]

After i cloes the Applications the Instances still be shown and can't be force closed.
[image: stays in Dock]
Same with the Dock only if I kill my Dock in my Terminal it reduces the symbol to 1.

Also the processes don't show up in my activity monitor.

Would be great if anyone could help me!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it' malware. I have the same problem after installing 10.11.5. 
I found a (not so nice) workaround:

When the app is still running: Save all changes and force quit the Application

When already quit the app: Open the Activity Monitor and force quit the Widowserver Process. You'll be logged out. Now restart the mac (don't just log in again) and you can use it without having the icons in the dock.

I think it's an 10.11.5 issue.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I am running 10.11.5 (but it did not occur to me to be a 10.11.5 issue). In my case, when I have the issue, I cannot restart my computer normally. Have this been reported as a bug?

Comment: But it does seem like the release date of 10.11.5 is roughly around when my computer start misbehaving

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Wacom Bamboo tablet, the BambooCore software can cause this issue to appear. Remove the application from your login items (System Preferences -> Users & Groups), and then restart (Maybe quitting bambooCore from Activity monitor may be enough)

I had the same issue and found the solution on this page, and it worked for me:

http://www.apple-art.com/Resolved-Symlink-icons-stuck-in-dock-after-OS-10-11-5-update_11318809.html

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences → Dock → Uncheck `Show recent applications in Dock`

Answer (score -1):

Right clicking on the Application's Dock icon, highlight over options, and unselect "Keep in Dock". You'll need to do this for all the Applications in Dock.

If you wish to have ONLY open applications in the Dock, here is a Terminal.app command you can run to change the preferences to show only open applications in the Dock.

```
defaults write com.apple.dock static-only -bool TRUE; killall Dock
```

to change back to normal replace TRUE with FALSE like so..

```
defaults write com.apple.dock static-only -bool FALSE; killall Dock
```

Just open terminal.app in your applications, copy and paste. This will reset Finder as well I believe, so finish any downloads first and any copying of files or moving to avoid interruption.

forgot to add: I'm not familiar with that specific program, but it also sounds as though you have a malware program. I suggest deleting the application entirely.

Edit: With the very little information given, I think you don't have all processes to be shown in activity monitor. By default only your user processes are shown. Those from Root user are not. If those GUI processes run by root are very dangerous and because you have multiple copies displayed on the dock, you must have multiple application copies across your files, I don't know of any other way multiple dock icons of the same application would display. This application looks to be acting out of control which is why I stated it may be malware. Best to securely delete all files for the application and reinstall a fresh copy correctly to halt the issues.

Comment: Electron is not malware. The static-only change does not apply here, as it is not what Philip is asking for. Electron wraps a Javascript/HTML5 program as a native Mac program. The problem is probably that the program crashes or similar, that leaves you with the Electron program "hanging around" but the actual wrapped program has ended. It would be useful to know if it is a standard program Philip downloaded, or it is something he is developing himself. The program must be visible from Activity Monitor, but may be named something else than Electron (for example look for node javascript engines)

Comment: Malware is not a program as a whole. Malware infects programs specifically to their benefit, it doesn't matter the program. But thank you for the background information of the application. I gave information on changing the Dock and what apps are shown as asked.